# Creating boolean masks from RGB pixel values python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rgb, boolean-expression

I have the following image masks with RGB values and corresponding classes:

1. BG:             255 0   0
2. face:           255 255 0
3. hair:           127 0   0
4. eyes:           0   0   255
5. nose:           0   255 255
6. mouth:          0   255 0

Now I want to have a boolean numpy array per class on pixel level, so that per pixel I have the corresponding class, i.e. a boolean array per class of [length, width] with True or False for each pixel depending on whether it belongs in that class.

For BG, mouth and eyes, I can simple copy axis 0, 1, or 2 and use np.bool to convert it to True or False (255 = True, 0 = False).

For the other classes however, I am struggling to get this to work without using a double for loop. Can someone help me to obtain what I want without using a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this?

```
labels = {'bg' : [255, 0, 0],
'face' : [255, 255, 0],
'hair' : [127, 0, 0],
'eyes' : [0,0,255],
'nose' : [0, 255, 255],
'mouth' : [0,255,0],
}

arr = np.random.choice([0,127,255], size=(3,500,500)) # simulated image



for key in labels.keys():
    key_img = (arr[0,...]==labels[key][0]) * (arr[1,...]==labels[key][1]) *     (arr[2,...]==labels[key][2])
    # do something with key_img
```

btw:

> For BG, mouth and eyes, I can simple copy axis 0, 1, or 2 and use np.bool to convert it to True or False (255 = True, 0 = False).

would lead to ambiguous labels. nose would score as BG and eyes, for instance

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage numpy broadcasting:

An example:

```
>>> pprint(labels)
{'BG': array([255,   0,   0]),
 'eyes': array([  0,   0, 255]),
 'face': array([255, 255,   0]),
 'hair': array([127,   0,   0]),
 'mouth': array([  0, 255,   0]),
 'nose': array([  0, 255, 255])}
>>> example
array([[[255,   0,   0],
        [127,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]],

       [[255, 255,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [255,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0]],

       [[  0,   0, 255],
        [255, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0, 255]]])
```

Using broadcasting the three channels can be checked simultaneously. Then using `all` along axis 2 we can select the points that satisfy all three equalities.

```
>>> masks = {k: (example==v).all(2) for k, v in labels.items()}
```

That's all. Result:

```
>>> pprint(masks)
{'BG': array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]]),
 'eyes': array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True]]),
 'face': array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False]]),
 'hair': array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]]),
 'mouth': array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]]),
 'nose': array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])}
```